Have strictly superharmonic functions on graphs been studied?
Given a graph $G$ and a function $f:G\to\mathbb R$, we say that $f$ is harmonic if
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{|N(x)|}\sum_{y\in N(x)}f(y)$$
for every $x\in G$, where $N(x)$ denotes the set of neighbors of $G$. Similarly, we say $f$ is superharmonic if
$$f(x)\geq\frac{1}{|N(x)|}\sum_{y\in N(x)}f(y).$$
It is well known that there are no positive harmonic functions in $\mathbb Z^d$ besides the constants. For $d\in\{1,2\}$, this is also true for superharmonic functions. However, in any graph with a transient standard random walk (e.g., $\mathbb Z^d$ for $d\geq3$), there are positive superharmonic functions given by expected number of visits of the random walk. In fact, this function is harmonic at every point but the origin of the random walk. Now, my question is: is the existence of positive superharmonic functions which are harmonic at no point known? Or, in other words, do we know for which graphs $G$ there are positive functions such that
$$f(x)>\frac{1}{|N(x)|}\sum_{y\in N(x)}f(y)$$
for every $x\in G$? I am particularly interested in the case of $\mathbb Z^3$.

Hello, welcom to mathoverflow. This site is for level research questions. You can ask general math questions on math stack exchange.

To give you hints about your question, I suggest to look at the Green function and the Riesz representation theorem for super-harmonic functions
